# Are there any implications about review paper acceptance if the proposal has been accepted?

Tags: peer-review, review-articles

So I recently submitted a proposal to a prestigious review journal. To my excitement, the proposal was accepted, and the journal has invited us to write a full review. Now the official policy of the journal is that acceptance of the proposal doesn't guarantee acceptance of the manuscript.

My question, I suppose, is mostly regarding how happy I should be about my proposal being accepted. How often do review papers get rejected if the proposal to write them was accepted? Is there still a good chance that our review paper could be rejected? Or does that typically only happen when authors of accepted proposals deviate a lot from the paper that they proposed to write?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

My experience is that review articles undergo peer review like any other article. So if you write a review on underwater basket weaving, it'll be sent to experts in underwater basket weaving, who might say things like "X group did a lot of work on the materials that give the best results, and you didn't mention their work at all". If the editors decide based on the reviews that you don't actually understand underwater basket weaving enough to be able to write a review, then it might lead to a rejection.

If you make a good-faith attempt to cover the field + address review comments though though, the chances of acceptance should be pretty good. After all, they did accept the proposal, which means they think a review article is appropriate + you're qualified to write a review.